# jquery text search

Tags: jquery, regex, search, text

i have html .

```
<body>

<span><font="color">
adfadf

23423423423

ORDER_NUMBER: </font></span><span>M123456JK98766</span>

</body>
```

i like to find a order number M123456JK98766 from html.
how can i retreive that? that number can be changed every time by using page refresh.

I have no option to add id against M123456JK98766.

Comment: pls give me jquery 1.5 function

Comment: here's jQuery function `$('body').html().match()`, you can write a regular expression, but you have to know what do you expect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var matches = $('body').text().match(/ORDER_NUMBER:\s?([A-Z\d]+)/);

if (matches[1]) {
    console.log(matches[1]); // 22M123456JK98766
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/DqCEG/).

Comment: @alex how do we check `console` value in **jsfiddle**?? is there any facility so?

Comment: @diEcho Unfortunately there is not one built in, but just add `window.console = { log: function(str) { alert(str) } }` and it will work for this simple scenario.

Comment: if <span> <font color="red">ORDER_NUMBER：</font></span><span>M110420J000002</span> then M110420J000002 can be changed every time then how can retrieve M110420J000002?

Comment: @msaif That is completely different to your original question.

Comment: I understand but i need to know again,pls help

Comment: @msaif You are probably better off asking a new question.

Comment: ... oh, so THAT's why he went and asked the same question again. hm.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is just assign an `ID` to the amount `span` like below.

**HTML:**

```
 <span> <font color="red">ORDER_NUMBER：</font></span><span id="orderNumValue">M110420J000002</span>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert($("#orderNumValue").text());
});
```

Comment: if <span> <font color="red">ORDER_NUMBER：</font></span><span>M110420J000002</span> then M110420J000002 can be changed every time then how can retrieve?

Comment: I have no option to add id=orderNumValue , then what will be the next soluntion. i tried in this way :                                    var x = /<span><font color="red">ORDER_NUMBER：</font></span><span>\s?([A-Z\d]+)/;
                var match = $('body').html().match(x)[1]; but not work